# How to update widget views instantly when button clicked

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget, receiver

I've seen a lot of answer here, none of them worked..! I just want a textview to get updated instantly once I click a button next to it.! I've tried to print a toast message and it shows normally, but updating views is the problem.

**My Code**

```
public class FollowersWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public static String REFRESH_ACTION = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";

  int x = 0;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent); 

    if (intent.getAction().equals(REFRESH_ACTION)) {
      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
      final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.followers_widget);

      x++;
      views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, x + "");

      int[] appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, FollowersWidget.class));
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views); 
    }

  }

  static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.followers_widget);

    try {

      String count = MyConfigureActivity.getNumCount(context, appWidgetId);
      views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, count );

      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refreshButton,getRefreshPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
  }

  public static PendingIntent getRefreshPendingIntent(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(REFRESH_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }

// other widget methods..
..
.
}
```

**My Manifest**

```
  <receiver android:name=".FollowersWidget">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/followers_info"/>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: you're working with remoteViews, this thing is under RPC. That's why it's pretty hard update these views frequently. Actually, just make your question more detailed

Comment: @AndrewBrowiski oh, how detailed exactly,? and do you have a solution for what I'm facing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally, I've seen a lot of ways to handle the onClick on widgets, but this way that worked out for me and it updates views intantally.

**Code**

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public static String REFRESH_ACTION = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE";
  static private RemoteViews views;
  private int x = 0;

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(REFRESH_ACTION)) {
      views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
      int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, TestWidget.class));
      x++;
      views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, x + "");
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
    }
  }

   static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget); 
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, x + "");
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, getPenIntent(context));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
  }



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
     for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }

    static private PendingIntent getPenIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(REFRESH_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out following code:

```
public class WidgetExample extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static final String REFRESH_ACTION = "YOUR_REFRESH_ACTION";
public static final String VALUE_KEY = "VALUE_KEY";
public static final String PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY = "PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(REFRESH_ACTION)) {
                int value = readValue(context) + 1;
                saveValue(context , value);
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetExample.class));
                for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
                    final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.followers_widget);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, String.valueOf(value));
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_refresh, getRefreshPendingIntent(context));
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    int value = readValue(context);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetExample.class));
    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.followers_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textv_count, String.valueOf(value));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_refresh, getRefreshPendingIntent(context));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
    }
}

private void saveValue(Context context, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(VALUE_KEY, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private int readValue(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPref.getInt(VALUE_KEY, 0);
}

public static PendingIntent getRefreshPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(REFRESH_ACTION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not update instantly !? when i click the button it updates the textview after a few seconds !?

Comment: @Alaa AbuZarifa Dude, the problem is that all operation is on another process, that's why you are using remoteviews, that contains some information about layout that are rendering on launcher process. You can't make updating widget instantly.

Comment: hmmm ok, then how to accomplish that then..? because there's tons of widgets out there that instantly gives some results such the Calculator widget, the stopwatch widget and the weather widget with the refresh button on it..! these all gives instant result when clicking a button .!? I thought I'd make a simple counter as an example.! there's gotta be a way.!